# Use of NOT EXISTS in SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I have read all most of the answers and even tried them. But this is my case where I'm inserting record from a `.csv` file into the database. I want to insert a record if it does not exist.

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO retailer(retailerCode, contact, shopName, address, 
                     retailerType, lastVisit, officeID, createDate) 
VALUES ('', '$emapData[1]', '$emapData[2]', '$emapData[3]',
        '$emapData[4]', '', '$id', CURDATE())
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT retailerID 
                  FROM retailer 
                  WHERE contact = '$emapData[1]')
```

Here `$emapData` is a PHP array that saves the records of the `.csv` file. The insert statement works fine without this part

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT retailerID 
                  FROM retailer 
                  WHERE contact = '$emapData[1]')
```

But my goal is not achieved.

Comment: What happens when you add the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement? It looks fine to me

Comment: Why don't using a unique index on contact column and `INSERT IGNORE ...` after ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql DBMS

Comment: After using where not exists , no record is inserted even if the record is not in the database.

Comment: `insert` queries have no `where` clause, period.

Comment: Did any answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WHERE with INSERT in that way.

What you can do:

As @Sylwit suggested, create unique index on contact and use INSERT IGNORE

```
alter table retailer add unique (contact)
```

Use INSERT INTO SELECT syntax

```
INSERT INTO retailer(retailerCode,contact,shopName,address,retailerType,lastVisit,officeID,createDate)
select '','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','','$id', CURDATE()
from retailer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT retailerID FROM retailer WHERE contact='$emapData[1]')
```

Comment: The code is not displayed correctly will you please edit it?

Comment: From your example I see that you use retailerCode in your columns part, but reatilerID in your where part. Do you really have two different columns? Also, please post which error you're getting, if my example doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I've two different columns. I'm not getting any error but the records are not inserted even if the table is empty